# Does it make sense for an API to return std::optional of a smart pointer to clearly specify that the pointer may be null?

Tags: c++, c++17

There is a bad habit in C++ to presume that when you call a function which returns some smart pointer `std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr` the value you get is "always" not null.

C++17 introduced new `std::optional` class which makes it extremely clear that the value may actually be null. I understand the advantage of `std::optional` for value types.

So I would like to know if it makes sense for the API to return optional values of smart pointers from a design point of view (where `nullptr` is a possible return value meaning that the object may not exist) ?

Let's say I have some class whose method returns some smart pointer:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::optional<std::shared_ptr<SomeSharedObject>> GetSomething();
};
```

Or is it too much of an overkill ?

Comment: Yes, this is overkill. Now the caller has to first check that the optional has value, and then to check that the pointer is not null. One check is better than two.

Comment: It adds on additional check if I want to use the API. Because even if the API tells me that the `shared_ptr` would never be `null` I would still need to verify that my self. The `std::optional` will only tell me if I get a `shared_ptr` or not and not if the `shard_ptr` is pointing to an object.

Comment: I had a discussion with some of my colleagues who argued with me stating they would prefer to have std::optional of smart pointer as it clearly gives an expectation to the user but I was wandering how common it may be to do such an interface.

Comment: Have you considered `std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>>`? :D

Comment: @AlexandreA. Depends what you want to state. An `std::optional<std::shared_ptr<T>>` might be something like, does not exists, has not been initialized yet but should exist and was initialized. At least that would be my interpretation of this construct if I see it. But if it is about if the object the smart pointer points to exists  or not (there are only two possible states), then `std::optional<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is misleading as it can hold three possible states.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this pattern. But opinion questions are off topic on SO (for one thing, it's difficult to rate the quality of an answer); voting to close.

Comment: If the null result is a failure, throw an exception instead. If it's a success or a partial success, just return `nullptr`. No `std::optional` needed. If you're constrained by a code style that forbids exceptions, you should be using something similar to boost's expected/outcome to signify errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on whether `nullptr` is a valid/expected thing for the function to return upon successful execution (it may or may not be, depending on what this function is supposed to do). If error handling via return values is what you want to do, then using an `std::optional` to signify the occurrence of an error may be a way to go. Consider, however, that doing this will not allow you to return additional error information. If the function is supposed to return ownership of an object upon success and anything else would mean failure, then you could use the `nullptr` state to signify an error and save the overhead of `std::optional` (it's small, but not completely free, since it has to track and test whether a value is present or not). Again, no possibility to pass error information, of course…